# How to detect client ipv4 and ipv6 address?

Tags: dns, ip, ipv6, ip-address

I want to create a webpage detecting (possibly dual-stack) client's ipv4 and ipv6 address, is there an easy way to do it without frames?
With frame I guess I can load two pages, each of them only available in IPv4 or IPv6 (Two domain names one with A record only and the other with AAAA only).
Is there another clean & easy way to do it?  http://test-ipv6.com/ can do it but I guess their implementation is pretty complicated for just showing the ip addresses.
Thanks.
I am thinking about doing it with php $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], but how can I pass it to other pages without ajax(which I don't know how to use)? The test page on a dual-stack domain name, 1 callback page on ipv4 only, 1 callback on ipv6 only. How can I pass the callback to the test page? If I use things like curl I get the server's address instead of the client's address.

Comment: How much are you paying me to design this for you?

Comment: I feel this is relevant to you: http://fud.no/ipv6/

Comment: @Kvisle that information is _way_ out of date.

Comment: Why go the easy route for a nigh on useless function?

Comment: @Alnitak It contains the ansers to realdreams' question - monitoring dual stack access haven't changed since then.

Answer (score 2):

You need AJAX or frames... You have to do two extra requests, one for IPv4 and one for IPv6. That cannot be done in one HTML page without either frames or AJAX.

Comment: Thanks I am thinking about image too. Request images from a IPv4/ IPv6 only host. It would still be nice to have text output (I am not going to type that IPv6 address...).

Comment: Well, yes, images would work. But they will show a broken image if the user doesn't have access to the protocol corresponding to that image...

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but you need create 2 subdomains at your DNS Server. The 1st should be IPv4 and the other IPv6 .

On ipv4.subdaomain.com, use only an A Record. On ipv6.subdomain.com use an AAAA Record.

Now, in your javascript send an AJAX request to ipv6.subdomain.com and ipv4.subdomain.com. In php return the ip address on the client.

Answer (score -2):

If you use a server side scripting language like PHP you can use the following code to do so

```
<?php
function look_me_up()
{
    $records = dns_get_record( trim(`hostname --fqdn`) );
    foreach($records as $record)
    {
        if ($record['type'] == 'A')
            $ip = $record['ip'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php

It does not need be in a frame, you could use a jquery ajax call to get the info if the page is not PHP. I am unclear of all the details of your existing page to make a good recommendation for portion of the question.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. I meant to get the address of the client. dns_get_record is very useful. The client's reverse DNS might be not be properly configured tho..